# How to use tf.pad without batch size axis?

Tags: python, css, tensorflow, padding

I'm trying to use `tf.pad` for image of shape `(?, M, N)`, here `?` is the batch size (not fixed) and `M`,`N` are image height, width, respectively. My tensorflow version is `1.14`.

For example, if the input `x` (with `dtype=tf.float32`) is from `MNIST`, then `M=N=28` with unknown batch size `? : (?, M, N)`.

To pad (zero) this image with padding size `: (1,1,1,1)` so the output size `(?, 30,30)`, I used the following code:

```
paddings = tf.constant([[1,1], [1,1]])

output = tf.pad(x[1:], paddings, "CONSTANT", constant_values = 0)
```

But it doesn't work. I think it's because `x[1:]` is not the each image `(M,N)`.
How can i use `tf.pad` to tensor `(?, M, N)` with `(1,1,1,1)` so the size of output image `(?,M + 2,N + 2)` in tensorflow version `1.14`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the `tf.pad` paddings is an integer tensor with shape `[n, 2]`, where n is the rank of tensor. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad

So you need to change the padding tensor like following:

```
img = tf.random.uniform((1,28,28))
print(img.shape)

>>> (1, 28, 28)

paddings = tf.constant([[0, 0,], [1, 1], [1, 1]])
img_padded = tf.pad(img, paddings)

print(img_padded.shape)

>>> (1, 30, 30)
```

I tested the code on tf 2.x but the same should also work with tf 1.x .

Comment: Thanks a lot! the problem is simple but sensitive.. :)